# Eventmachine fails with Segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, android-c2dm, eventmachine

I'm using Eventmachine to send C2DM messages on googlephones. And when i've trying to send push message, i've get segmentation fault and stacktrace:

```
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/projects/taxi/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/eventmachine.rb:179: [BUG] Segmentation fault
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | 
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | -- control frame ----------
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | c:0006 p:---- s:0021 b:0021 l:000020 d:000020 CFUNC  :run_machine
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | c:0005 p:0248 s:0018 b:0018 l:000017 d:000017 METHOD /home/dmitry/projects/taxi/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/eventmachine.rb:179
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | c:0004 p:0058 s:0011 b:0011 l:002270 d:002270 METHOD /home/dmitry/projects/taxi/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pace-0.0.6/lib/pace/worker.rb:30
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | c:0003 p:0106 s:0007 b:0007 l:000538 d:000780 EVAL   c2dm.rb:8
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000538 d:000538 TOP   
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | ---------------------------
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | -- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | c2dm.rb:8:in `<main>'
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/projects/taxi/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pace-0.0.6/lib/pace/worker.rb:30:in `start'
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/projects/taxi/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/eventmachine.rb:179:in `run'
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/projects/taxi/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/eventmachine.rb:179:in `run_machine'
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | 
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | -- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_vm_bugreport+0x61) [0x7f202b486641]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x5f77e) [0x7f202b37077e]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_bug+0xa5) [0x7f202b3715a5]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x10be04) [0x7f202b41ce04]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x36420) [0x7f202afa8420]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/.rvm/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8(EVP_MD_CTX_md+0) [0x7f2028991820]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0(+0x24c9c) [0x7f2027c38c9c]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0(+0x1da86) [0x7f2027c31a86]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0(+0x1f510) [0x7f2027c33510]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0(+0x14d36) [0x7f2027c28d36]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0(+0x18cf0) [0x7f2027c2ccf0]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0(+0x20c1b) [0x7f2027c34c1b]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/projects/taxi/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/rubyeventmachine.so(_ZN8SslBox_t12GetPlaintextEPci+0x39) [0x7f2027e7c039]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/projects/taxi/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/rubyeventmachine.so(_ZN20ConnectionDescriptor20_DispatchInboundDataEPKci+0x70) [0x7f2027e7aad0]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/projects/taxi/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/rubyeventmachine.so(_ZN20ConnectionDescriptor4ReadEv+0x9c) [0x7f2027e7abcc]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/projects/taxi/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/rubyeventmachine.so(_ZN14EventMachine_t14_RunSelectOnceEv+0x2da) [0x7f2027e7ebca]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/projects/taxi/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/rubyeventmachine.so(_ZN14EventMachine_t8_RunOnceEv+0x28) [0x7f2027e7fab8]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/projects/taxi/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/rubyeventmachine.so(_ZN14EventMachine_t3RunEv+0x58) [0x7f2027e81698]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/projects/taxi/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/rubyeventmachine.so(+0xf4c9) [0x7f2027e744c9]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x16ec36) [0x7f202b47fc36]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x164f68) [0x7f202b475f68]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x16ae4d) [0x7f202b47be4d]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_iseq_eval_main+0xb1) [0x7f202b4819b1]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x658e2) [0x7f202b3768e2]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(ruby_exec_node+0x1d) [0x7f202b37769d]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /home/dmitry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(ruby_run_node+0x1e) [0x7f202b3797be]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | ruby(main+0x4b) [0x40082b]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x7f202af9330d]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | ruby() [0x400859]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | 
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | [NOTE]
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | Bug reports are welcome.
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | 
14:24:51 c2dm.1    | process exiting
14:24:51 api.1     | process terminated
14:24:51 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

Comment: More details are needed; did this ever work? Has eventmachine ever worked? Does eventmachine run even a simple "hello world" program? Why are your pathnames referencing ruby 1.9.1 (which I didn't think lived long enough to make an impression) but your interpreter error messages are all 1.9.2? Is there a newer eventmachine beta or full release you could try? Do you need to rebuild your libcrypto bindings after a libcrypto or libssl update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by replacing libssl-dev from Ubuntu 11.10 with libssl-dev from Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: How You did that? I use 11.10, and got this really annoying "You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries."

Comment: I have remove all the ssl package from the system and install them from 11.04 packages manually. There are a lot of dependencies so it can be hard to do)